# how to add an Arrow icon inside my React Js Project

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, icons

I am working on 3rd party ReactJS SPFx SharePoint web part. and inside the code i have the following markup to show 2 icons-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon';
import styles from './SingleNews.module.scss';
import { ISingleNewsProps } from './ISingleNewsProps';
import News from '../News';
//code goes here...

<span className={ styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__likes}>
    <Icon className={styles.icon} iconName='Like' />
        post.likes}
</span>
<span className={ styles.singleNews__content__info__reactions__comments}>
    <Icon className={styles.icon}  iconName='ActionCenter' />
        {post.coments}
</span>
```

[image]

now i want to show this icon (arrow) and color it as orange, but not sure what is the icon name?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
iconName='DecreaseIndentArrowMirrored'
```

**Edited ans Below**

Try this `iconName='DecreaseIndentArrowMirrored-xl'` or `DecreaseIndentArrowMirrored-lg`

reading [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/fabric-core#:%7E:text=Use%20Fabric%20Core%20icons,of%20contents%20at%20Colors.) might also help you

Comment: i tired your code, but it show a very tiny arrow ,,, not sure why?

Comment: plz try the edited answer